# What is the best way to use Index Match in this case?

Tags: excel, indexing, match, formula

In the primary worksheet, I have a list of employees in column A, from columns D:ZZ I have basically a calendar in row 11.  Where these intersect, I have assigned a task code to each employee to illustrate what they are employed to do that day.  I want to dynamically color the coded cell based on the date in the row 11 and code from the column that it was entered.  In my second sheet, I have a table of the codes along column A.  From columns B:AM, in row 2 (under the header) I have another code that says what type of work it is, in office, on the road, etc. This is the code I am trying to look up with Index Match.  In the row with the task code, under each header I have a scheduled date that that particular job will be either in or out or nothing.

I can Index the task column pretty easily, my problem is how would I take the row I get from that, then search only that row for the date that I applied the code to the employee to return the result from row 2 and the column that that date appears?

I have a pretty good understanding of Index/Match in looking up multiple items to return a result.  I am having a problem creating a range from a result to find the data I want.

I have tried Indirect and Address as well as Offset, but I don't want this to be volatile as it is being used in conditional formatting over several thousand cells.

Task Code Schedule Worksheet

```
DAY     1   2   3   4   ...
CODE    A   S   A   F   ...
96T003  03 May  04 May  05 May  06 May  ...
96T004  05 May  06 May  07 Jun  10 Jun  ...
96T005  05 May  19 Jul  22 Jul  23 Jul  ...
```

Primary worksheet

```
            SAT SUN MON TUE WED
     DATE   01  02  03  04  05                  
     JONES  OFF OFF 96T003  96T003  96T004
     DAVIS  OFF OFF 96T003  96T003  96T005
```

This formula works, but is "volatile" and I am leary to use it in a conditional formatting function.  Is there a way to make it not as volatile?

```
 =INDEX(CMP_FLYCODE,1,MATCH(F11,INDIRECT("'CMP'!"&ADDRESS(MATCH(F19,CMP_ADP,0),1)&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH(F19,CMP_ADP,0),40)),0))
```

CMP_FLYCODE is a reference to just the A, S and F code row

Expecting to return a letter code A, S or F based on the date and code

Edit: Added the header to the code schedule that is a unique number for the day of the task 1, 2, 3...

Comment: So you wrapped one INDEX/MATCH into the other? Also note that your dates don't match up. If you tried to match these values you'll return a `#N/A`

Comment: Do you have 2 "A"s?  If you try to match the same key, what is your logic for discerning which of those to use?  [I'm looking at your first example, where headers are "A", "S", "A", "F", "..."]

Comment: So here is the logic, each task (i.e. 96T003) takes exactly 39 days to complete.  Each day is scheduled for a calendar day.  Day 1 of task 96T003 is on 3 May and it is an (A)cademic day, no travel, Day 2 is on 4 May and it is a (S)imulation day and so on.  I have tried to wrap INDEX/MATCH, but I cannot convert the row in which I found my code (96T003) to a range to look up the date in without generating an error or without using INDERECT or ADDRESS (volatile)

Comment: Edited to show a working formula with INDERECT/ADDRESS.  I am searching for a solution without them?  I will be using this formula in 3 conditional formatting rules to color code the cell based on the 3 codes, A, S and F.  Just applying it to one is nearly crashing Excel, XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's too bad, you can just get the entire row from the 2d array B3:E5 in the task sheet using index with the match for the task code in the row parameter and 0 in the column parameter, then match the date in that and use index again to get the required letter code.

This is what my formula looks like:

```
=IF(C3="OFF","",INDEX(Tasks!$B$2:$E$2,MATCH(C$2,INDEX(Tasks!$B$3:$E$5,MATCH(C3,Tasks!$A$3:$A$5,0),0),0)))
```

This is my primary sheet:

[image]

This is my task sheet:

[image]

So to use this in conditional formatting, you would need three rules using custom formulas

```
=INDEX(Tasks!$B$2:$E$2,MATCH(C$2,INDEX(Tasks!$B$3:$E$5,MATCH(C3,Tasks!$A$3:$A$5,0),0),0))="A"

=INDEX(Tasks!$B$2:$E$2,MATCH(C$2,INDEX(Tasks!$B$3:$E$5,MATCH(C3,Tasks!$A$3:$A$5,0),0),0))="S"

=INDEX(Tasks!$B$2:$E$2,MATCH(C$2,INDEX(Tasks!$B$3:$E$5,MATCH(C3,Tasks!$A$3:$A$5,0),0),0))="F"
```

with appropriate fill colours.

[image]